# Automate grant authorize from authorization link generated by OAuth2

Tags: python-3.x, oauth-2.0, python-requests

[image]

Based on the picture, it stated that the `code` and `state` arguments can be obtain once I opened that created authorization url manually in browser and grant the authorization

But what I need is to let the script grants the authorization automatically and retrieve the `code` and `state` arguments without me to manually grant the authorization

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the Authorization Code Flow headless (without user/browser interaction).

You may want to look into [Client Credentials flow](https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/client-credentials-flow) to implement machine to machine authentication.